# SOQL order by desc of FAQ__VoteStat by NormalizedScore not returning results in the expected order

Tags: soql, articles

Problem description:

The following SOQL query:

```
[SELECT Id, ParentId, NormalizedScore, Channel 
 FROM FAQ__VoteStat
 WHERE ParentId IN : knowledgeArticleIDs AND Channel =: channelName
 ORDER BY NormalizedScore desc
 LIMIT 5];
```

Returning results in unexpected way, for example:
If I have 3 articles with the following NormalizedScore:

```
Article 1: 0
Article 2: 0
Article 3: 3
```

I received the result order as follow:

```
Article 1: 0
Article 2: 0
Article 3: 3
```

When I was expecting to receive the following order:

```
Article 3: 3
Article 1: 0
Article 2: 0
```

Solution help needed:

I don't understand why the Order By Desc not working, it's seems weird.
I know I can sort the articles manually from code, but that seems redundant, maybe there is something I missed regarding the NormalizedScore field, which can explain why the order by is not working properly.

Thank in advanced!

Comment: Does this go wrong for values other than zero? I wonder if the underlying values are null as [nulls sort first by default](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm).

Comment: I already tried 'nulls last', it's still got the same result. I also tried with another article with score of 3.9, and he does goes first, but then I still got zeros in the middle and the last article with score 3, I was trying few other variants and still got weird ordering results (not in descending order!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much reading and searching, [I have found that this is the standard behavior](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm):

> NormalizedScore - Description:  "Article's weighted score on a scale of 1 to 5. A higher score means more votes. **Articles without recent votes trend towards an average rating of three stars.**"

So that means (and I checked it) that if an article is never voted, it will have a score of zero, but Salesforce will look at it as score of 3 (stars). So if you have articles with the following scores:

- a1: 2
- a2: 0
- a3: 5
- a4: 0

the order will be:

- a3: 5
- a2: 0
- a4: 0
- a1: 2

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a relative of a known issue referenced below. Looks like sorting in code it is.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SU4fAAG

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, this is probably the solution they had for the Cold Start problem.